# Adobe Captivate Google LMS Widget - suddenly not reporting

Tags: widget, reporting

We are using this widget: http://captivatedev.com/2012/07/19/adobe-captivate-6-x-widget-google-lms-with-email-reporting/

Suddenly this morning we realised that it is no longer recording information into our google sheets. It was working fine yesterday. The company that we purchased the widget from has closed down, and I cannot find anyone to contact for support.

Any ideas on what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old post so you probably found your solution.

What worked for me...

I changed the way that I create my links.

Before I used... 
http://yourwebserver/yourcaptivateprojects/your%20project/index.html

Today I use...

http://yourwebserver/yourcaptivateprojects/your%20project/your%20project.htm

I still finish the project choosing the 'flash' and 'html' option.

I really like the widget; logging results to a Google spreadsheet is very cool. It is too bad that the solution only works with flash installed on the device.

Regards,

Chris